# Insert DateTimeOffset to subform

Tags: odata, priority-web-sdk

I'm trying to insert (POST) new row into sub-form with DateTimeOffset column type

```
"TIMESTAMP@odata.type": "#DateTimeOffset",
```

I'm trying for example to pass this JSON

```
{
    "TIME_STAMP":"2019-04-09T21:31:23+03:00",
    "SOME_ID":6
     ....
}
```

every time I got the error 500, but if I'm sending this JSON without the date column it just created fine.

maybe do you familiar with the option how to insert the information into the sub-form?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your example this field is called **TIMESTAMP** and not **TIME_STAMP**. 
Therefor your JSON should look like this:

```
{
"TIMESTAMP":"2019-04-09T21:31:23+03:00",
"SOME_ID":6
 ....
}
```